# GTK# window .Fullscreen() not working in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: c#, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, monodevelop, gtk#

there.
I have class, inherited from Gtk.Dialog

```
public partial class RelaxDialog : Gtk.Dialog
```

And there is how I want to make in fullscreen

```
var dialog = new RelaxDialog(time,text);

dialog.KeepAbove = true;
dialog.Fullscreen ();
dialog.Run();
```

Sounds strange, but it works in Kubuntu 14.04 and Xubuntu 14.04, but doesn't works in Ubuntu 14.04.

What can be the issue? Kindly advice.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=M%3aGtk.Window.Fullscreen), calling `Fullscreen()` is not a guarantee that the window will be fullscreened. `Fullscreen()` just requests the window manager to do so. It's up to the window manager whether to grant that request or not.

Apparently the Unity window manager doesn't.

Comment: So, there is no way to make window fullscreen if .Fullscreen() doesn't work?

Comment: You could fake it by resizing the window as large as the screen, but that is also a request that the window manager isn't required to grant.